# MATLAB: Remove white background in 'saveas' function

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I am cropping a image in matlab 2013a with imcrop and saving it by using the function saveas. The issue I face is that a white background is save with the image although the figure shown by imshow only shows the image without the white background. Need help to remove that white background

**CODE:**

```
clc
clear all
close all
I1=imread('IMG_1956.jpg');
I=imshow('IMG_1956.jpg');

h=imrect(gca,[0 0 270 125]);
pause
pos=getPosition(h);
s=imcrop(I1,pos);
na='IMG_1956.jpg';
na=na(1:end-4);
fi=strcat(na, '_.png');
H=imshow(s)
saveas(H,fi);
```

Comment: Try `imwrite` https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html

Comment: Its a figure dont have the image data matrix

Comment: Try `imwrite` as Yvon suggested, or if you have reasons to need to save the image as it appears on your figure window, then set the axes size to fill the figure window

Comment: try `getframe` and then `imwrite`

Comment: @AnderBiguri that won't get rid of the 'whitespace' around the axes, will it?

Comment: imwrite worked! The image data from imcrop was directly used to save the image. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works for me.

```
I1=imread('Jellyfish.jpg');
I=imshow('Jellyfish.jpg');

h=imrect(gca,[0 0 270 125]);
pause
pos=getPosition(h);
s=imcrop(I1,pos);
na='Jellyfish.jpg';
na=na(1:end-4);
fi=strcat(na, '_.png');
H=imshow(s)
imwrite(s,fi);
```

Solution: Use `imwrite` with `H.CData` or `s`